# What stories and characters are referenced in this painting of a Science Fiction and Fantasy Lounge?

Tags: character-identification, object-identification

This image depicts a fantasy version of the [Storm Crow Alehouse](http://www.stormcrowalehouse.com/), a real-world fantasy themed tavern. This one is obviously filled with various references to fictional works. Can we identify the whole list of them?

[image]
Click for full resolution, or visit the [artist's page](http://zen-master.deviantart.com/art/Storm-Crow-Alehouse-Cover-604190045).

Comment: a head start for whoever wants to post an answer: Geralt of Rivia from _Witcher_ front-left; Boba Fett image above him; Data to the right of that, Navi at the bar, Majora's Mask on the back wall.

Comment: Maybe Cthulhu on the second table, but not sure, also a Star Trek char next to him(don't know the series at all). First at the bar is the protagonist from fallout (4 i believe?) and a Storm Trooper helmet next to him and Yoda, the DnD dice close to the crow, and next to it the Necronomicon(?), also Cloud's sword next to the first painting (upright). A lightsaber and Frostmourne(from WC) at the far end. The Deathly Hollows sign above the bar next to Frostmourne. Han Solo(frozen state) under Majora's mask, and next to Han is a Face hugger (?), next to it is Solaire Of Astora(?).

Comment: Can't recognize any other or zoom more because it's a small picture

Comment: Nice work on the super high res version CreativeEdge.

Comment: Is it fair to say that *most* of these are "villains"?

Comment: Also, **awesome photo!** Can you link to the reddit source?

Comment: @Mooz I added the original artist's source link.

Comment: @Mooz Data? Mal Reynolds? Inigo Montoya? Geralt? None of the ones I recognise are villains.

Comment: @Rand I wouldn't know a single one of those... Lol

Comment: Someone who's regularly at those communities should post comment to that Reddit thread and the Deviantart page to direct people here.

Comment: You should do [The Storm Crow Tavern](http://zen-master.deviantart.com/art/Storm-Crow-Menu-Illustration-537318595), too.  Also try identifying things in [the](http://boredinvancouver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/stormcrow-tavern-1024x384.gif) [real](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/09/cd/77/storm-crow-tavern.jpg) [tavern](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/70/da/a5/storm-crow-tavern.jpg)

Answer (score 25):

I'll add a rough coordinate grid drawn on top of the image so it's easier to name which parts of the image we're talking about.  (There's so many objects and characters in this image and it's hard to tell which ones are significant that I don't dare to number them individually: I'd surely leave some of them out.)

[image: (same image with a rough coordinate grid drawn on)]

### Mounted objects (upper row)

- A5: unidentified picture
- D1: Vigo painting (Ghostbusters 2)
- F2: Cloud's Buster Sword (Final Fantasy VII)
- G2: unknown painting
- H3: weapon maybe, possibly a mace?
- J3: Majora's Mask from the Zelda videogames of Nintendo
- M3: possibly Luke's green light saber (*Star Wars*)
- N3: Frostmourne, Arthas's sword from Warcraft III

### Mounted objects (head height)

- I4: Han Solo frozen in a carbonite block from *Star wars*
- K4: Head of a Rancor, creature from *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* ([see image of real world statue](http://d2ciprw05cjhos.cloudfront.net/files/v3/styles/gs_large/public/galleries/16/02/stormcrowalehouse01.jpg))
- Q4: Deathly Hallows sign

### Posters on the columns

- C3: Boba Fett (*Star Wars*)
- D3: Bossk (*Star Wars* bounty hunter)
- F4: Tank Girl from the eponymous comic book and film (this one is easy, there's actually a yellow on white text saying "TANK GIRL" above her).
- G4: [poster for Barbarella: queen of the Galaxy film (1968)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarella_%28film%29)
- H4: *One Million Years B.C.* (1966 Film)

### Characters

- A4: unknown gunman shooting a blaster, visible only as silhouette
- A5: unknown person facing the camera
- D6: Geralt of Rivia, character from *Witcher*
- E5: unknown floating black sphere or head
- F5: H. P. Lovecraft holding Felis
- G5: Illithid from D&D
- H5: Commander Data from *Star Trek TNG*
- I6: The protagonist from [*Journey* 2012 video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_%282012_video_game%29)
- J5: Malcolm Reynolds from *Firefly*
- L6: [Sir Bedivere](https://66.media.tumblr.com/a8f1c632191226b17d46d2183cc8afbd/tumblr_inline_mgskynIKyP1r8lpsh.jpg), from *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*
- M6: Inigo Montoya from *Princess Bride*
- N5: Death from Neil Gaiman's *The Sandman*
- O4: Navi from the *Avatar* movie
- P5: [Angela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_%28comics%29) from Marvel Comics
- R5: A Vault Dweller from Vault #117 (Fallout videogame series)
- S6: Yoda from *Star Wars*
- T5: bartender, possibly Rachel from *Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak*; or Jubilee, a mutant from Marvel comics

### Table in the middle

- E6: cards of the Gwent collectable card game from the *Witcher* series, held by Geralt
- F7: unidentified chalice
- G7: Gwent game being played by Geralt and the journeyer
- G6: unidentified flat black object with white icons to the left of the collectible cards

### Table in front

- D9: possibly Tom Riddle's diary with a basilisk tooth in it
- K9: d20 dice
- K9: some sort of magic rune circle drawn directly on the table
- Q8: drinking glass
- O7: black songbird, probably one of the storm crows to match the name of the bar
- O9: a Black Lotus from *Magic: the Gathering* trading card game in a vase (NB. based on Chris Rahn's illustration of the card in the Vintage Masters online-only set, not the more iconic original illustration of Christopher Rush)

### Other

- O3 to T2: five more black songbirds
- T6: Finn's helmet from *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* (notice bloody handprint) on bar counter

(This is a community wiki answer. If you can identify even just one item, feel free to edit it, or leave a comment if you don't have edit privileges.)

Comment: aww, maybe the grid is the way to go.

Comment: The wizard creature in red robes is the protagonist from the game 'Journey'.  The devs have called it 'the journeyer', but I don't think that's official.

Comment: Also, wouldn't Geralt be playing Gwent?

Comment: The unknown gunman looks like Luke on Hoth. Can't remember if he ever fires his blaster though.

Comment: Those G6 objects with white icons... Aren't they the cards face down?

Comment: Also D9 is not "possibly". It literally says "Tom Riddle's Diary" on it. Can't edit easy on mobile right now

Comment: The flock of birds around Q3 may be ravens or crows in a reference to A Song of Ice and Fire.

Comment: O7 might be the Raven. E5 looks like a head floating above shoulders, not just an unattached sphere.

Comment: Is F5 [Vincent Vega](http://pulpfiction.wikia.com/wiki/Vincent_Vega) perhaps?

Comment: I believe E5 is "The Invisible Man" often portrayed with a floating hat : For examples: http://www.loyalbooks.com/image/detail/Invisible-Man.jpg and/or http://orig07.deviantart.net/9102/f/2010/138/1/1/invisible_man_by_dan121314.png

Comment: Hmm, A5 possibly Connor MacLeod from Highlander?

Comment: F5 kinda looks like the protagonist from Twin Peaks

Comment: There are some sort of creatures hanging at Q3, R3, and S3.  E4 being hit by the raygun appears to be a character, too.  You've also forgotten the ceiling lamps.  (-:

Comment: A4 : Perhaps a poster of superman holding a girl in his arms similar to : https://wearesitcom.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/supermansecret_post2.jpg

Comment: @JdeBP: Near [Q-S3] I think those are lamps or parts of the lamp, not creatures.  I don't see how the lamps are relevant at all.

Comment: FWIW, I combed through about 3000+ images of the real Storm Crow Tavern on Twitter, Yelp, Instagram, Google Image, and a few different news articles. I wasn't able to find any more real-world equivalents of some of the props than what has already been pointed out in these 2 answers.

Comment: You aren't being very sharp-eyed, then.  In [this real-world picture](http://stormcrowalehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/leah-whole-bar-1-1200x801.jpg), for example, the hanging creatures that I mentioned, which b_jonas didn't even recognize as creatures, are some sort of dragon.

Comment: @JdeBP: I don't think that dragon is in the painting though.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't know what you're talking about. There's nothing on the lamps in Q/R/S3. Nothing hanging off the lamps in that real picture--which I saw a few times--is hanging off them in the painting. What is on there, Cthulu and mead/tavern mugs. If you look to the right of the image you linked, you'll notice the axe head that I mention in the other answer, and that the unknown picture next to it is still obscured (and this is pretty much the best shot of it. In some pictures, those objects are there yet/any more).

Answer (score 7):

I *think* I identified all the revelant persons and objects. All are from left to right. As I made this a community wiki, feel free to fix it where wrong.

### Mounted Objects (upper)

- Vigo painting (Ghostbusters 2)
- Cloud's Buster Sword (Final Fantasy VII)
- Unknown painting
- Metal loops directly behind unknown gunman:

  - [image] (real world version)
- An axe:

  - [image]
- Majora's Mask
- Green light saber (Luke's)?
- Frostmourne (Warcraft III)

### Mounted Objects (far wall)

- Han Solo in Carbonite
- Rancor Head (confirmed by finding real-world pictures of this object on social media)
- Deathly Hallows sign

### Columns

- Boba Fett
- Bossk (Star Wars bounty hunter)
- Tank Girl (you can see here face cleary if you zoom in, not a Storm Trooper)
- One Million Years B.C. (1966 Film)

### Characters

- unknown gunman
- [Geralt of Rivia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geralt_of_Rivia), from the Witcher franchise.
- Floating black sphere
- Twilight Zone Narrator or Klatu?
- Illithid
- Commander Data (ST:TNG)
- protagonist of the 2012 video game *Journey*
- Malcolm Reynolds
- Black Knight
- Inigo Montoya
- Death from Neil Gaiman's *The Sadman*
- Na'vi from *Avatar*
- [Angela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_(comics)) from Marvel Comics
- A Vault Dweller from Vault #117 (Fallout videogame series)
- Jubilee (women in blue and gold)?
- Yoda

### Bar

- Finn's helmet from *The Force Awakens* (notice bloody handprint)

### Card Table

- Magic The Gathering game
- goblet?

### Front Table

- Tom Riddle's diary with basilisk fang
- d20 Die
- [The Storm Crow](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-H00xNKBWwFg/UGUuLnOiNCI/AAAAAAAACYQ/a-XSK_ErE0g/s1600/storm_crow_signage.jpg) (as in The Storm Crow Tavern (alehouse))
- A black lotus from Magic: The Gathering
- glass

Comment: @mooz, could be, other people say Death from Sandman, I put a question mark because I don't know.

Comment: My money for the redhead is on Red Sonja

Comment: To clear up confusion, the artist tagged the image with #thesandman, which makes it pretty clear the women is Death from that series.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that the redhead is [Angela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_(comics)) from Marvel and Image comics, and have edited accordingly.

Comment: [Here's the real-world version of the head in the back of the alehouse](http://d2ciprw05cjhos.cloudfront.net/files/v3/styles/gs_large/public/galleries/16/02/stormcrowalehouse01.jpg)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the big bird in front is the titular Storm Crow.

Comment: That is definitely NOT Magic: The Gathering.  It almost looks more like Spellfire...