# What ships are on this T-Shirt?

Tags: object-identification

[image: T-shirt image]

I came across this T-shirt mentioned on Facebook, with a link to where you can [order](https://pro.teechip.com/campaigns/-/-/stores/scifi4ever/ship10a?retailProductSlug=4AC6927E56E4B3-103BCCBC41CE-GS1-TC0-NAV) it from, and got a higher quality image from it.

Now, I know most of them:

- A. Top left : Star Fury - B5
- B. Central back: A Stargate - Stargate
- C. Top right: X-Wing - Star Wars
- D. Middle Left: ? - Enemy Mine?
- E. Central front: The Enterprise - Star Trek
- F. Left:  Shadow Battlecrab - Babylon 5
- G. Right: Red Dwarf - Red Dwarf
- H. Lower Left: Battlestar Galactica - Battlestar Galactica
- I. Bottom Centre: Moya? : Farscape?
- J. Bottom Right: Andromeda Ascendant? : Gene Roddenberry's Andromeda?

**Question**:
Can you confirm/identify D, I & J

**Bonus**:

B. From which planet is this gate

E. What version of the Enterprise?

H. Original or remake?

Any corrections on any of the others?

Comment: I'm pretty sure E. is D (NCC-1701-D) and B. is a Milky Way Stargate. This reminds me of this question (not a dupe).  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133742/54605

Comment: `H. Original or remake?` Battlestar Galactica?  There was **no original**, only the remake. (In the same way that there were no Matrix sequels, or Star Wars prequels...)

Comment: It might be best if you gave a community wiki answer, which invites us all to fill in any blanks left. That's how these "identify multiple object from one image"-questions are usually answered. Did you buy the T-shirt?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**In order to fully answer the question I have converted my answer to a community wiki. Please edit as required.**

### **A**

Starfury, Babylon 5 (possibly a [Heavy Starfury](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Starfury))

### **B**

This is a stargate from the Stargate movie and associated TV shows.

In answer to the bonus question about the Stargate. I suspect it is the Earth gate most commonly seen at Stargate Command.

[image: Stargate symbol]

The highlighted symbol is the point of origin glyph for Earth. Here is a clearer version:

[image: Earth Glyph]

This is used to fill the 7th chevron with the current planet you are dialing from.  All of the chevrons are active, which means rotation has stopped.  The last chevron, the one top-center, is "point of origin" therefore this is definitively the earth-stargate.  Pegasus(SG-Atlantis) and Destiny(SG-Universe) have dots and sequences of circles and lines as their glyphs.

[Source](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Point_of_origin)
[Source](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Chevron)
[Source](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_address)

### **C**

This is a T-65 X-Wing from the original Star Wars trilogy.

### **D**

This is the [SSV Normandy SR-1](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/SSV_Normandy) from the original Mass Effect game.

[image: Normandy SR1]

### **E**

This this the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D), a Galaxy class starship, from Star Trek: The Next Generation.

### **F**

This is a Shadow attack craft from Babylon 5.

### **G**

This is the mining ship Red Dwarf from the BBC comedy show of the same name.

### **H**

This is the BattleStar Galactica from the 2003 TV remake.

### **I**

This is Moya from the TV show Farscape. [Farscape wiki page of Moya.](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Moya)
Farscape wiki contains 5 pages with different leviathans and this one most similar to Moya

[image] [image]

### **J**

This is the [Andromeda Ascendant](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Andromeda_Ascendant) - from the T.V. series [Andromeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_(TV_series))

[image]

Comment: @Beofett I have converted this to a community wiki. Please [edit] where appropriate.

Comment: Is a star gate a ship? =p

Comment: @jpmc26: [Only sometimes](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Asuran_Stargate_satellite)

Comment: @jpmc26 [Each component of the Supergate was also space-worthy](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/File:Sg1-9x06_3939.jpg)

Comment: Is it ever stated that the Earth glyph only appears on the Earth gate?  If each gate had its own point of origin glyph that didn't appear on the others, then there wouldn't be any need to lock that one in; the gate could just automatically send it.  Requiring the point of origin makes more sense if the physical gate could conceivably be located on different planets, and needs a way to specify which one.

Comment: As in the comment to my answer stated, there are addresses containing symbols, which are point of origin symbols. It is propably a milky way stargate based on its design.

Comment: @Ray when they get to Abidos in the film they comment that it has different symbols. This might be worth its own question...

Comment: here's a link to an answer I was making.  there are a few images referenced which might be helpful here.  https://pastebin.com/kgRgahkH  either someone cares to add them to this answer, or they don't and it is no big loss.

Comment: @Ray I think it's more like a null terminating byte. The addresses are different lengths (There are known addresses of 6 to 9 symbols, I think.), so entering the origin point tells the gate, "end of address."

Comment: @jpmc26 No. Each glyph specified a location in space. Lines are drawn between each pair, and the point of intersection of those three lines is the destination.  And the Å-looking glyph (How is the actual symbol not in Unicode yet? Everything else is.) specifically represents Earth.  So they use 6 symbols to specify one location and one symbol to specify another location.  It may not have been thought out well, but that *is* how it works. Variable length addresses were brought in later in the series, but for the most part, they were all 7 symbols long.

Comment: @Ray Ʌ̊ does the job with a capital turned V + combining ring.

Answer (score 4):

D is the [Normandy SR1](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/SSV_Normandy) from the Mass Effect video game series.

[image]

The Enterprise is NCC1701-D

Comment: How can you say it's SR1? :D

Comment: The "fins" on the sides are longer for the SR1, the SR2 is much thinner in appearance.

Comment: I think the asker|querant wanted an image or two showing the resemblance, and maybe by comparison.

Comment: As the highest upvoted answer, can I recommend you turn this answer into a Community wiki answer and include all the other answers here, rather than have 5-6 different answers. This is normally how object-identification questions work if you don't know all the answers.

Comment: Some examples: [A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133745) [B](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146188) [C](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107467/what-are-the-names-of-all-the-sci-fi-vessels-in-this-artwork)

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it only answers part of the question.  If this questions gets changed to Community Wiki (I'm not convinced that's the right course of action, though), the reputation loss should be reversed after the fact.  Please consider editing to address all the points in the question in the meantime.

Comment: Further to @Beofett's comment, the [top answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163431/31394) has now been made community wiki, so that everyone can edit - please consider **adding your info here to that answer** (instead of converting this one to CW too).

Answer (score 2):

Normally i don´t like to repeat already mentioned informations (especially since some of them were already in the question), but since i was asked to complete the answer:

- A. Top left : Star Fury - B5
- B. Central back: A milky way Stargate - Stargate
- C. Top right: T-65 X-Wing - Star Wars
- D. Middle Left: SSV Normandy SR-1 - Mass Effect
- E. Central front: The Enterprise (NCC-1701-D) - Star Trek
- F. Left:  Shadow Battlecrab - Babylon 5
- G. Right: Red Dwarf - Red Dwarf
- H. Lower Left: Battlestar Galactica - Battlestar Galactica
- I. Bottom Centre: Moya - Farscape
- J. Bottom Right: Andromeda Ascendant - Gene Roddenberry's Andromeda

Bonus Answers:

B: Cant say from which planet but from which galaxy, it is from the milky way, since the pegasus gates have different chevrons (symbols, milky way more like letters, pegasus more like star constellations)
[milky way](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Milky_Way_stargate.png) vs [pegasus](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Pegasus_stargate.png)

E: It is the galaxy class [as seen here on memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_class)

H: remake, [the original looked like that](http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/012/9/0/battlestar_galactica__tos__ortho_by_unusualsuspex-d71q3iv.jpg)

Comment: It's the Earth's alpha gate because it has the Ʌ̊ as the point of origin (the top right glyph), isn't it?

Comment: @AndreKR That was a plot point in the original movie, but the series mostly dropped it. Plenty of star gates in the Milky Way have the same point of origin (and more importantly, all the other symbols, which are constellations *as seen from Earth*). So the best we can say is "not one of those that have been shown to have different symbols", e.g. Abydos. Season seven finale explicitly mentions that all the symbols have their "syllable" in Ancient, which makes it clear they are intended to be universal, or at least nearly so (a deviation would also imply gates cannot dial all the other gates).

Comment: If @C.Tomm converts there answer into a Community-wiki answer, please consider adding your answer to the community wiki answer.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it only answers part of the question.  If this questions gets changed to Community Wiki (I'm not convinced that's the right course of action, though), the reputation loss should be reversed after the fact.  Please consider editing to address all the points in the question in the meantime.

Comment: Further to @Beofett's comment, the [top answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163431/31394) has now been made community wiki, so that everyone can edit - please consider **adding your info here to that answer** (instead of converting this one to CW too).

Comment: @AndreKR: In the movie this might have been the case but in the series a point of origin could also be a part of a different address. As you can see here http://rdanderson.com/stargate/glyphs/glyphs.htm

Comment: @AndreKR - broken link

Comment: It's @IIOIOOO's link, but here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20190416073339/http://rdanderson.com/stargate/glyphs/glyphs.htm